# Finding values of a constant related to a sequence - BMO 1993 P3

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

> **1993 British Mathematical Olympiad, Round 1, Question 3**
>
> For each positive integer c, the sequence $u_{n}$ of integers is defined by $u_{1} = 1$, $u_{2} = c$, $u_{n} = (2n+1)u_{n−1}−(n^2−1)
> u_{n−2},(n
> ≥ 3)$

> For which values of $c$ does this sequence have the property
> that $u_{i}$ divides
> $u_{j}$ whenever $i ≤ j$?

**What I'd tried :**

Well since comparing $u_{i} | u_{j}$ was lil more complicated I thought i may find some interesting in the sequence , so I went on computing :

$u_{1} = 1$,

$u_{2} = c$,

$u_{3} = 7c - 8$,

$u_{4} = 48c - 72$,

$u_{5} = 360c - 600$,

$u_{6} = 3390c - 5280$,

. . . .

But as u can see it wasn't too much helpful . So how should this problem be approached ?

Comment: To continue, note the conditions require that $u_2\mid u_3$, so $c\mid 7c-8$. Since $c\mid 7c$, then $c\mid 8$, which means there are only a few values to try checking.

Comment: @JohnOmielan but how far to check the sequence isn't of finite terms it is upto n terms

Comment: @Ash_Blanc But since $c \mid 8$, you only need to check $c=1,2,4,8$. You'll rapidly find you don't need to check any farther than you've already gone.